# how to read excel file into R and run it as a html (i am getting error)

Tags: html, r, excel

```
[r]
library(tidyverse)
require(xlsx)
read_xlsx("Churn.xlsx")
df <-read_xlsx("Churn.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: try `library(readxl)`

Comment: You wrote `read_xlsx` but the name of the function in the `xlsx` package is `read.xlsx`.